# How to display nested array data fetched from several API pages

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to display a bunch of articles data from an API. The API data is paginated to 20 objects per page. I've managed to obtain and store them in an array but now it's one array but with several arrays nested inside it and the nested arrays inside the array is what I'm trying to access if that doesn't sound confusing.

So it now look like this: `mainArray.nestedArray.articles(object)` I want to shorten it to `mainArray.articles` without the `nestedArray`.

I've tried ES6 and concatenating but it returns:

```
    undefinedundefined[object Object]undefinedundefined[object Object][object Object]undefinedu
```

when I used

```
    for(let i=latestPage; i>1; i--){
        apiArticles += apiArticles.concat(allArticles[i]);
    }
```

**I'm also doubtful that I cant merge them as they are an array of promises:** Is there any way to display all the nested array's data in the main array in the setState segment?

```
    Array [
      Promise {
        "_40": 0,
        "_55": null,
        "_65": 0,
        "_72": null,
      },
      Promise {
        "_40": 0,
        "_55": null,
        "_65": 0,
        "_72": null,
      },
      Promise {
        "_40": 0,
        "_55": null,
        "_65": 0,
        "_72": null,
      },
      Promise {
        "_40": 0,
        "_55": null,
        "_65": 0,
        "_72": null,
      },
```

**Full code**:

```js
componentDidMount(){
  let allArticles = [];  
  var apiArticles = [];

  fetch(BASE_URL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      return fetch(responseJson._links.last.href)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      var captured = /page=([^&]+)/.exec(responseJson._links.self.href)[1]; 
      var latestPage = captured ? captured : '100';

      for (let i=latestPage; i>1; i--) {
        allArticles.push(fetch(BASE_URL + '&page=' + i)
          .then(res => res.json()));
      }

      console.log(allArticles);

      // for (let i=latestPage; i>1; i--){
      //   apiArticles = [...allArticles[i]];
      // }

      Promise.all(allArticles)
        .then(articlesJson => this.setState({
          loading: false,
          dataSource: articlesJson[1].articles.reverse()
   }))
})
```

I should be able to access all the articles via

```js
articlesJson.articles.reverse()
```

instead of

```js
articlesJson[1].articles.reverse()
```

Here is a sample of my json response (slightly redacted). This is one of the nestedArray[1].articles

```
"articles": Array [
      Object {
        "_links": Object {
          "self": Object {
            "href": "https://api.example.com/v2/articles/9113",
          },
        },
        "content": "<p>test</p>",
        "created_at": 1555319812,
        "id": 9113,
        "image": "https://example.jpeg",
        "owner_id": 14415,
        "owner_name": "TEST",
        "owner_type": "organization",
        "short_description": "short test",
        "slug": "slug test",
        "title": "test title",
        "total_comment": 0,
        "total_like": 0,
        "updated_at": 1555319841,
      },
```

Comment: How does the output of `console.log(allArticles);` look like?

Comment: @Tim     it looks like this    Array [
          Promise {
            "_40": 0,
            "_55": null,
            "_65": 0,
            "_72": null,
          },
          Promise {
            "_40": 0,
            "_55": null,
            "_65": 0,
            "_72": null,
          },
          Promise {
            "_40": 0,
            "_55": null,
            "_65": 0,
            "_72": null,
          },
          Promise {
            "_40": 0,
            "_55": null,
            "_65": 0,
            "_72": null,
          },

Comment: Can you show us a piece of your json response? Add it on the question

Comment: added the json response at the bottom